# Get the sum of one column multiplied by the total of another, using ActiveRecord queries

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, aggregate-functions, rails-activerecord

Say I have a table with integer columns `no_of_units` and `average_revenue_per_unit`. To get the total revenue for any one row, I just need to calculate `no_of_units * average_revenue_per_unit` - simple enough. But what if I want to calculate the total revenue for the entire table?

The obvious way would be:

```
total_no_of_units = TableName.sum(:units)
overall_average_revenue = TableName.average(:revenue_per_unit)
total_revenue = total_no_of_units * overall_average_revenue
```

But it feels icky having to use two separate SQL queries. Is there a way I can do this with just one chained ActiveRecord query? Or could I (and should I) do it using raw SQL?

EDIT: I've just realised my above sample code is wrong! `overall_average_revenue` is the average of all the integers in the `revenue_per_unit` column... but this isn't the same thing as the actual average revenue per unit, because different rows have different numbers of units. I need a weighted average. Back to the drawing board...

Answer (score 2):

This will work, although it is a bit of raw SQL.

```
TableName.pluck('sum(units) * avg(revenue_per_unit)').first
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to my original question... but I've just realised that my question is flawed and this doesn't give the actual average revenue! (See my edit to the question). Have an upvote anyway...